# Rename remote machine, disable bitlocker for one reboot using Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, bitlocker

What would be the best way to use powershell to script this scenario?  We have a few machines that we need to rename, disable bitlocker for one reboot, reboot?  Its not many and I want to improve my powershell chops.  This is what I have so far:

```
$OldName = Read-Host 'What is the hostname of the machine you want to rename?'
$NewName = Read-Host 'What would you like to rename the machine to?'
Read-Host -Prompt "This will reboot the remote machine!  Press any key to continue or CTRL+C to quit" 
$cred = get-credential    
Rename-Computer -ComputerName "$OldName" -NewName "$NewName" -DomainCredential $cred -Restart
```

I wasn't sure if I could pipe to suspend bitlocker 1 reboot, or whats the best command for a remote machine.  I know you can use a .csv list for a bunch of machines, but this is not that many.

Answer (score 0):

manage-bde -protectors -disable c:
is a batch command but works inside a powershell script as well. After one reboot, BL will re-enable automatically.

Comment: Thanks.  How would you revise this line below to include that and run it on a remote machine though?  Rename-Computer -ComputerName "$OldName" -NewName "$NewName" -DomainCredential $cred -Restart

Comment: Leave that line as is, but put it behind the line that disables bitlocker protection.